# How can I clean an old metal photographic plate? What are best practices for conservation?

Tags: cleaning, restoration

As someone who 'knows about photography' I've been handed some old metal (possibly copper?) plates which look like they were at one time used for in a printing press for some kind of short run, but I'm more than happy to be corrected.

They've been stored in a box in a church for quite a while and have a few mucky bits on but otherwise seem to be in fairly good condition.

[image: Printing plate sample]

I'm looking to identify what they are and recommendation on best practices for cleaning & storage.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because restoring printing plates aren't photography related.  It's really more of a metalworking question.

Comment: If not here then where in the SE network would you guys suggest that restoring and preserving these photographs would be better placed?

Comment: I think it's just not clear to people that these are photographic plates. You're in the right place for that.

Comment: @JamesSnell - there probably isn't a place, but the best I could say would be to try and scan it and see if you can touch it up, but if you want to restore the plate itself, you need someone familiar with metal restoration which has as much to do with photography as how to drive to a studio unfortunately.

Comment: @mattdm - I'd rather hoped the picture would give it away. :)

Comment: @mattdm - it may be a plate of a photograph, but the restoration of it is a specialized field of it's own that is unrelated to photography.  I think it may be a bit too distantly removed even if the subject of it is something that was used at one time to duplicate a photo.

Comment: @AJHenderson - my intention is to do both really, get the image from this original and clean the plate up, primarily clean the plate since I'd need a good original.  I'll have a hunt around SE and see what I can find to get the right input.

Comment: @JamesSnell - I know a guy that does metal restoring.  Problem is I can't remember who it was.  I just remember talking to them about it.  I'll let you know if I can figure out who it was and I can see if they might be willing to point you in the right direction.  Looking up antiques in the phone book might also be a good place to find out more.  I know it involves chemical treatments and other ways of cleaning the plate, but I don't know any details.

Comment: I don't think this is any different from restoring an old photograph in any other medium.

Comment: @mattdm - yeah, I agree, but film is a traditional photographic medium, maybe care of metal printing plates is more in the realm of old photography than I think, but I would tend to classify that more as the realm of printers than photographers.  If we have someone that can answer it, I wouldn't object to keeping it open on the site, but I'm not sure who here would have that skill set.

Comment: I'll add my two cents to this already extended discussion in the comments(this does seem on topic to me). 1.) Not all questions fit on an SE site, and just because it doesn't fit on one well, doesn't mean we leave them open here 2.) Just because no one _here_ currently may be able to answer a question, does not make it off topic.

Comment: I have a similar problem but Kerosene isn't cleaning the plate fully. Is there a stronger option?

Comment: I believe this falls well within the realm of photography. It's a **photographic** plate. I don't see why print on paper or print on a plate is any different. Printing our photographs is well within the realm of photography. I'm a bit surprised at the debate here. I believe the question should remain, as photography has been around for a very long time, and a very wide range of mediums have been used to produce photographs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recognize these. I've made them. It is a copper printing plate. They are screened for use directly onto the paper, probably in a letterpress since they are flat.

They are made by exposing a print (copy) in a large process camera with a vacuum back to hold the film perfectly flat during a long exposure. The resulting very dense high contrast "lithographic" film is then contact printed onto a sensitized copper plate (gum bichromate process). The plate is put into an acid etch bath that eat away the exposed portions and leaves the unexposed portions (a dot screen) in a relief. Ink sits on the high spots that hit the paper when an inked plate (That's what you're looking at) and paper are pressed together in a printing press.

There's more but you'll find everything on the Internet. If not, I can answer any question you may have. I've done it and taught it. I still have a press in my living room that would accept it and make a nice print from it. :)

Edit: I see there're tacks on the edges. They hold the thin chamfered etched copper plate onto a piece of wood - probably plywood - to raise the surface to the international standard type height of 0.918 inches.

Cleaning is easy, wipe it with a slightly oily (keroscene) rag to soften and remove any ink hardened in the surface although it looks well cared-for by the last printer's devil (assistant). The rich patina of the aged copper can be removed to make it sparkle as new; but, that will remove some of the very detailed etched surface of the plate. It is best cleaned not polished to maintain its original integrity. Store flat or on edge. Caution: Copper is a soft, easily-scratched metal. Once scratched, cannot be repaired. For durability, copper plates were chrome-plated.

This would've made a nice cross post with the graphic design group, too.

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/80416/49477 - you may add something to your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure there's much to do with graphic design here!

Comment: @mattdm It's a physical artifact of a (arguably the only) technique to reproduce an image with ink on paper—photomechanical tone separation which has been replaced by software used everyday by every graphic designer.