# How to clean an old metal newspaper photo engraved plate?

Tags: cleaning, restoration

I have an old metal engraved plate of a picture of my family that was used by the newspaper back in the 1950's.  Unfortunately, it has a lot of white type spots of some kind of powder/crystal growth over some of the photo.  Is there anyway that I can safely clean the photo plate?

Comment: This is a cool question! I'm no expert, but it might help to have an picture of the plate and growth for when an expert does come along.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I clean an old metal photographic plate? What are best practices for conservation?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/42335/how-can-i-clean-an-old-metal-photographic-plate-what-are-best-practices-for-con)

Answer (score 2):

If this is a thin metal sheet with the picture visible as a negative in slanting light, this plate was used on an offset press and the plate is probably aluminum.
The white coating on the surface is possibly just an oxidized surface.
Try making a paste with cream of tartar and small amount of warm water to form a paste. 
With a clean cotton rag try rubbing a spot on a non-critical area and rinse.

(There are commercial aluminum cleaning powders but I can't vouch for their abrasiveness.)

In the movie 'To Live and Die in L.A.', Willem Defoe is a counterfeiter and you can see the entire process of creating a offset plate.

My father had a printing business and I remember these plates quite well.

reference:
Kipphan, Helmut (2001). Handbook of print media: technologies and production methods (Illustrated ed.). Springer. pp. 130–144. ISBN 3-540-67326-1.

Comment: Do you know why Al was used? I'm guessing because Al is softer than steel and hence the engraving tools would last longer.

Comment: Unless we are talking about a different process, no engraving tools are use.  This is a photoengraving process which involved a full size negative made from the original with a large camera, then the negative is laid on a sensitized aluminum (?) sheet and the plate exposed using a brilliant electric arc for a period of seconds. Then the plate is 'developed' by rubbing with some sort of solution that removes a bit of materials. In this references (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoengraving), there was a mention of zinc, so the sheets mat be a metal which is zinc-coated rather than aluminum.

Comment: Got it. I've always just thought that "engraving" was physical and "etching" was all chemical processes.

Comment: Me, too but I use the terms as I found them.

Comment: Would this be intaglio, if the plates are physically etched, as opposed to photo-litho? [I've worked in the latter industry, using photo-sensitive coated plates, but never seen the former.]

Comment: My experience from my teens working in my dad's print shop is that any plates used in offset printing are photo-lith and chemistry is used to 'develop' them. 
physical etching/burnishing is well out of my experience.

Comment: Intaglio is carving, Lithography is etching.

Comment: The film is amazing but Intaglio would be the better way to go than Lithography if you wanted to counterfeit money. Then there's the paper to cloth raq percentage used in real money that you'd have to do (money is 50% cotton/50% acid free paper). Money countermeasures have so improved since 1985 too. Weirdly one of the world's biggest counterfeiters is North Korea.